# Access to VPN hosted in virtualbox

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, vpn

So the school provides a VPN for us to use but it only has a Windows client, it seems like its a custom client developed by them.
I am currently using a laptop, mint (also have a ubuntu desktop) as the distro. What i am doing now is to use the windows in virtual box to activate the VPN. Is it possible to allow my main OS (mint/ubuntu) to use the VPN connection? I've tried the NAT setting but it did not work.

I've seen post on VPN on the main system and allowing virtualbox to access it, but no luck on what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of the guest OS, you are a wire-tapping attacker here. If the VPN connection is secure, this should not be possible the direct way. However if it is custom-build chances are that it is not secure. This is impossible to tell without knowing more about the client (or the server).

What you could do even if it is secure is:

- analyse/research the vpn client: Find out which protocol is used and whats is the secret (the certificate, the password ...) and then find a proper Linux client for the same protocol
- add a second network adapter and route the traffic from host to the guest and then into the VPN